# Can superadmin query all transactions on a chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Irrespective of where a chaincode is installed (that is, any org), can Fabric client superadmin query all transactions?

Answer (score 0):

No. The transactions can only be queried by identities that are part of an organisation that is part of a channel where the transaction was created.